# Windows Cmd line delete command to delete all file except one

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I am looking for a single windows command where I need to delete all the files in a folder except one.

eg: Files listed under directory:

- c:\users\admin\folder

  - abc
  - abcde.zip
  - abcdef
  - 123.txt

Now, I want to delete all the files except "abcde.zip"

corresponding Linux command would be: `rm -rf !(abcde.zip)`

Is there anything like this on windows without using batch script, just a single line command?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can run from command prompt (it's still batch, there are multiple commands in a single line): `for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b ^| findstr /v /b /e /c:"abcde.zip"') do (del /f "%f")`. Note that it only works for files.

Comment: Thanks Cristi! This works well. What if I want to delete files and directories both under a specific path, could you help out with that please?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/112136/ms-dos-command-to-delete-all-files-except-one

Answer (score 0):

Since *Win*'s command interpreter doesn't have a `rm -rf` like command (that works on both files and dirs) we just need to modify the command that I placed in my 1st comment, actually split it in 2 commands (still in a single line: well, if the console is really really wide :) ), and execute them in a sequence (`&`):

- one that takes care of the files (the `/a:-d` argument for dir), and launches `del`
- one that takes care of the folders(the `/a:d` argument) and launches `rmdir`

Here's what it looks like (note that it does the job for the *current directory*):

```
(for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /a:-d /b 2^>nul ^| findstr /v /b /e /c:"abcde.zip"') do (del /f "%f")) & (for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /a:d /b ^| findstr /v /b /e /c:"abcde.zip"') do (rmdir /q /s "%f"))
```